# Why is Django DRF urlconf not resolving url with query param

Tags: django-rest-framework, query-string, urlconf

I have a urlconf with some standard paths and where the paths may optionally have a get paramerter in the form "?format=xlsx".

As I read the DRF documentation, query parameters are ignored by the URLConf resolver.

But , when I add a query parameter like "? format=xlsx to a path that otherwise matches, it no longer matches and I get a "not found" response.

My URLConf is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', MyListAPIView.as_view(), name="list"),
    path('<sysid>/',MyRetrieveAPIView.as_view(), name="get"),
    path('<sysid>/timeline/',MyTimeLineAPIView.as_view(), name="timeline"),
]
```

For some reason '22/timeline/' matches but '22/timeline/?format=xlsx' does not.

Why is the query string not being ignored?

Answer (score 0):

when call the '' url and then MyListAPIView view is running, you can access the query_params in this way:

```
request.query_params
```

by URL of: /?page=3 we get:
[image]